# The table owner is different than the partitions owner

Tags: postgresql

I am using Flyway as a migration strategy to roll out db changes and I used this method to create a table with user_A. Moreover I, manually, partitioned the table using a different user (user_B) with higher privileges. I used pg_partman and a cron job.

That caused the table to have as owner the user_A but the partitions being created by pg_partman have as owners the user_B. As a result the user_A cannot alter the table anymore.

How do I untangle this? I cannot recreate the table and using the higher privileged user is not recommended.

Comment: Change the ownership of the table partitions, using user_B or a superuser.

Comment: The existing, yes, but this is an automated process and daily new partitions will be created.

Comment: Your automated proces can also set the owner. Or use a different database role for this automated proces, user_A.